# HashingVectorizer with DecisionTreeClassifier in scikitlearn

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a dataset with about 110k rows and I want to classify it using `DecisionTreeClassifier` in Scikitlearn. So, i have a question here: Is it possible to using `HashingVectorizer` with `DecisionTreeClassifier` in Scikitlearn? Could you please tell me with some example code? Thank you so much.

Comment: What did you try yourself to find out? Welcome to StackOverflow, take the few minutes for [learning how it works best](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :-)

Comment: Any reason you think it wouldn't work? Looked at the example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_multiclass.html#example-ensemble-plot-adaboost-multiclass-py?